# React - useEffect: Dependencies when component is rendered via map

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am currently stuck employing React's useEffect Hook. The project I am working on is quite complex, but I will try to break it down to the relevant parts in order to describe my issue.

**A) The Child Component**

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";


const ChildComponent = props => {
    const [needsConfirmation, setNeedsConfirmation] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        setNeedsConfirmation(
          !!props.someObject.someArrayOfObjects.find(({status}) => status === "added")
);
    }, [props.someObject]);

   // I SKIP THE RETURN PART
}
```

**B) Inside The Parent Component**

```js
const ParentComponent = props => {
    const renderChildComponent = someObject => {
        return (
            <ChildComponent
               someObject={someObject}
            />
        ) : null;
    };

   return (
      <>
         props.someArrayOfObjectsHandledByRedux.map(renderChildComponent)
      </>
   )
}
```

**C) The Problem**

Inside the child component I would like the useEffect hook to take effect every time something about the property `props.someObject` changes. The latter one is an app-wide state handled by Redux. Of course, I made sure that the corresponding reducer function always returns a brand new object after an action has taken place.
The relevant code inside the reducer function looks something like this:

```js
        case ActionTypes.SOME_ACTION_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                someObject: formattedResponse(data),
            };
```

However, no matter what I did, I just cannot get the useEffect to take effect. Using the ReduxDevTools I could clearly verify that the reducer function has successfully returned a new state object. Nevertheless, the useEffect hook inside the child component did not recognize any changes in the dependencies.

For now, I have implemented a very ugly workaround by always creating a brand new object which is handed to the child component

```js
    const renderChildComponent = someObject => {
        return (
            <ChildComponent
               someObject={{...someObject}}
            />
        ) : null;
    };
```

But this is very inefficient as it automatically re-renders all child components, even though, typically, only the data of one particular child component might have changed.

Does anybody have an idea what the problem in this particular case might be?

Thanks a lot for your input in advance.

Comment: I am very sorry for the late response. Thank you very much for your comment. Not calling the child component as a function solved the issue.

Comment: That was general recommendation though, a bit weird it helped with `useEffect`; if you can share reproducible example, I could try to look what was the issue